# Cant open custom ports on VM instance

Tags: firewall, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to acess my website that is on my oracle cloud instance on port 8082 via public ip and can't make it.

**Cloud instance**

> *curl localhost:8082*
> :works

**Firewall settings**

ALL default ports open
[image]

**From outside**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your application actually listening on all interfaces, or only on localhost? Maybe check what netstat shows for port 8082 - whether it has 127.0.0.1:8082 or 0.0.0.0:8082.

Comment: thanks. worked for me. silly me forgot to change the application ip. to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Have you open the UFW?

Take a look to instructions in
https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/enabling-network-traffic-to-ubuntu-images-in-oracle-cloud-infrastructure

```
sudo ufw app list
sudo ufw allow 8082
sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: Ufw interrupts the oracle internal firewall. Ive tried it

Answer (score 0):

First Connect with your cloud service provider they can open it or maybe they are blocking it for some security purpose.

Comment: cant be. i've got my own subnet and i am able to cofigure everything.

Comment: Which VM you are using? OS name?

Comment: Oracle cloud. Ubuntu latest.

Answer (score 0):

disable Ubuntu's default firewall via

> `sudo ufw disable`

then install firewalld

> `sudo apt install firewalld sudo systemctl enable firewalld`
>
> `sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp sudo`
> `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=443/tcp sudo`
> `firewall-cmd --reload`

[Fore More Info](https://smalldata.tech/blog/2021/09/08/how-to-open-ports-on-oracle-cloud-vm-running-on-ubuntu-20-04)